# Google geojsonlayer polygons with hover effects using android

Tags: android, google-maps, hover, polygon, geojson

i am confused about to make a hover effects for the polygons in geojson layer using android google map.i have revived the geojson details from the web server to show the things on map.i want to make an hover effects for the polygons in the geojson layer when the user finger moves around on it.below i posted my code how i implemented the geojson layer using google map.Thank you in advance.

**strong text**
class DownloadGeoJsonFile extends AsyncTask
{

```
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected GeoJsonLayer doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            // Open a stream from the URL
            InputStream stream = new URL(params[0]).openStream();
            String line;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Read and save each line of the stream
                result.append(line);
            }
            // Close the stream
            reader.close();
            stream.close();
            return new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, new JSONObject(result.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be read");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be converted to a JSONObject");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(GeoJsonLayer layer) {
        Log.e("sundar","success");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (layer != null) {
            Log.e("sundar","successsuccess");
            addGeoJsonLayerToMap(layer);
        }
    }
}
private void retrieveFileFromUrl()
{
    new DownloadGeoJsonFile().execute(getString(R.string.geojson_url2));
}
private void addGeoJsonLayerToMap(final GeoJsonLayer layer)
{
    if (layer != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.e("sundar", "successsuccess");
            layer.addLayerToMap();
            final GeoJsonPolygonStyle style =layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
            style.setStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);
            style.setStrokeWidth(3F);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(20.593683, 78.962883)));

            layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature)
                {
                    Log.e("type",feature.getGeometry().getGeometryType().toString());

                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("exception","exception occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i made it with the below code.

```
private void addGeoJsonLayerToMap(final GeoJsonLayer layer)

{

    if (layer != null)

    {

        try

        {

            Log.e("sundar", "successsuccess");

            layer.addLayerToMap();

            /*polygon style*/

            final GeoJsonPolygonStyle style = layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
            style.setStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);
            style.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);

          /*  style.setFillColor(R.drawable.map_hover_button);*/
            style.setStrokeWidth(3F);

        /*its for setting markers with infowindow*/
            for (GeoJsonFeature feature : layer.getFeatures())
            {
                GeoJsonPointStyle pointStyle=new GeoJsonPointStyle();
                pointStyle.setTitle(feature.getProperty("Name"));
                pointStyle.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.locpin));
                feature.setPointStyle(pointStyle);
            }
            layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(newGeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature)
                {

            Log.e("type",feature.getGeometry().getGeometryType().toString());
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),feature.getProperty("Name"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        toast.show();
                        Handler handler = new Handler();

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()

                        {

                            @Override

                            public void run()

                            {

                                toast.cancel();

                            }

                        }, 500);
                        if(feature.getGeometry().getGeometryType().equalsIgnoreCase("Polygon")||feature.getGeometry().getGeometryType().equalsIgnoreCase("MultiPolygon")) {

                            if (coloredfeature != null)

                            {
                                GeoJsonPolygonStyle lineStringStyle = new GeoJsonPolygonStyle();

                                coloredfeature = (GeoJsonFeature) feature;

                                lineStringStyle.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);

                                lineStringStyle.setStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);

                                lineStringStyle.setStrokeWidth(3f);

                                lineStringFeature.setPolygonStyle(lineStringStyle);

                            }

                            GeoJsonPolygonStyle lineStringStyle = new GeoJsonPolygonStyle();

                            lineStringFeature = (GeoJsonFeature) feature;

                            coloredfeature = (GeoJsonFeature) feature;

                            lineStringStyle.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#991A6659"));

                            lineStringStyle.setStrokeColor(Color.WHITE);

                            lineStringStyle.setStrokeWidth(2f);

                            lineStringFeature.setPolygonStyle(lineStringStyle);

                        } 

                }

            });

        }

        catch(Exception e)

        {

            Log.e("exception","exception occured");


        }

    }

}
```

one issue is i unable to get the properties of multiple polygons while we clicked it.any help would be appreciate.